# Enunciate Json Generated Filename

Tags: json, enunciate

I have several same name data types in my code in different namespaces. When generating the XML Enunciate names these files as xml_*namespaceID_datatype*.xml this works correctly. Unfortunately the JSON files generated are named as json_*datatype*.json and do not keep the *namespaceID*. This is problematic as multiple same name datatypes are not kept.

How do I alter the naming of JSON files produced to retain the namespaceID?